# How update properly VueJs .env files

Tags: vuejs2

Getting old value still after updating with the fresh new values

```
VUE_APP_API_URL="http://example.com/api/"
```

Is there a command to clear the cache?

I have event build my project again... :(

Comment: clear cache of your browser and try again

Comment: I know it's late but, you just needed to restart the npm server.